# Trouble with shadowing @property in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, properties, variable-assignment, setter, categories

**Why isn't a setter synthesized for `myString` in the example below?** The basic assignment below results in `myString` being `nil`. Trying to use the setter `[self setMyString:s];` results in an unrecognized selector exception.

```
// in .h file
@interface MyClass
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *myString;
@end

// in .m file
@interface MyClass (MyCategory)
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *myString;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthensize myString;

- (void) someMethod:(NSString *) s {
    myString = [s copy];

    // why is myString nil here?
}

@end
```

**Edit**: the problem was with gdb. `po myString` printed `Can't print description of a NIL object.`. However `NSLog(@"myString: %@", myString);` printed the expected value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other two answers are correct, but I think they miss your intention. It's common to declare a property as read-only in the .h file, so that code outside the class implementation can't write it. Inside the .m file, you want it to be readwrite. This kind of redefinition is *explicitly supported*. However, you need to put the redeclaration as readwrite in a class-extension:

```
// In your .h file:
@interface MyClass : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *myString;
@end

// In your .m file:
@interface MyClass () // Note the empty parentheses
    @property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString *myString;
@end
```

You do still need to use `self.myString = aString` or `[self setMyString:aString]`, instead of writing to the ivar directly as you're doing right now.

Comment: I didn't know about this. Looks like it could come in handy. You mention that it is explicitly supported - do you have a link to the docs for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Will: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW19

Comment: @WillPragnell Read about [Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html). *A common use for class extensions is to redeclare property that is publicly declared as read-only privately as readwrite...*

Comment: Note that as mentioned in Josh's link, while redeclarations of properties are fine, you have to repeat the original declarations attributes exactly, with the one exception of readonly->readwrite. This means that copy vs. retain must be specified in the original declaration. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to declare a publicly readonly, privately writable property. You should do that in a *class extension* rather than a *category*. Syntactically, a class extension looks like a category with no name:

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *myString;
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a property with the same name in both your MyClass interface and your MyCategory category seems like a bad idea. Remove the declaration in the category and I expect all will be well.

Comment: I think the OP's trying to create a publicly read-only, privately read-write property.

Comment: @mipadi I agree, and your answer shows how to do that correctly.